# Simple python and vtk code not working. Why?

Tags: python, vtk

I have to say that I'm new with Python, especially with vtk (8.1.1). I'm using PyCharm and I added the vtk interpreter.

I wrote this code to display a simple cube with vtk, but the only thing it does is opening a black window with nothing inside.

```
from vtk import *
# Generate polygon data for a cube
cube = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
# Create a mapper for the cube data
cube_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cube_mapper.SetInputData(cube.GetOutput())
# Connect the mapper to an actor
cube_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
cube_actor.SetMapper(cube_mapper)
cube_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
# Create a renderer and add the cube actor to it
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
renderer.AddActor(cube_actor)
# Create a render window
render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
render_window.SetWindowName("Simple VTK scene")
render_window.SetSize(400, 400)
render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)
# Create an interactor
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)
# Initialize the interactor and start the
# rendering loop
interactor.Initialize()
render_window.Render()
interactor.Start()
```

Where am I wrong?

Thanks for your help,

Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call *cube.Update()* before you call *cube.GetOutput()*

```
from vtk import *
# Generate polygon data for a cube
cube = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
cube.Update()

# Create a mapper for the cube data
cube_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cube_mapper.SetInputData(cube.GetOutput())
# Connect the mapper to an actor
cube_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
cube_actor.SetMapper(cube_mapper)
cube_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
# Create a renderer and add the cube actor to it
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
renderer.AddActor(cube_actor)
# Create a render window
render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
render_window.SetWindowName("Simple VTK scene")
render_window.SetSize(400, 400)
render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)
# Create an interactor
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)
# Initialize the interactor and start the
# rendering loop
interactor.Initialize()
render_window.Render()
interactor.Start()
```